# Adding an option to a select box, if the option is not already listed

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How can I additionally add function to the existing javascript code, such that when a new value provided in the field1 and is not listed in the select box, that the code will:

1. Check if the (field1) value is already listed in the select box, if it is, then select its value in (field2) and;
2. If the value provided in the field1 is not listed in the select box (field2) then add the new value from (field1) and select it in (field2)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s66qg6xp/

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                document.getElementById('field2').value = document.getElementById('field1').value
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="field1">
        <br>
        <select id="field2">
            <option value="apples">apples</option>
            <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
            <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your code within `<code></code>` tag or use **snippet code** please.

Comment: What did you try? Looks like it's a ' do it for me' question

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {

var alreadyInList = [];
var allOptions = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
// populate already in list
for(var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
    alreadyInList[i] = allOptions[i].value;
}

var input = document.getElementById('field1').value;
for(var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
    if(alreadyInList.indexOf(input) > -1) {
        // element is already in the list
    } else {
        alreadyInList.push(input);
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = input;
        option.text = input;
        document.getElementById('field2').appendChild(option);
    }
}

}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="field1">
<br>
<select id="field2">
<option value="apples">apples</option>
<option value="oranges">oranges</option>
<option value="bananas">bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       function test() {
            var NewOption=document.getElementById("field1").value;
            var options=$("#field2").children().filter(function (){return $(this).text()==NewOption});
            if (options.length==0){                
              document.getElementById("field2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("field2").innerHTML+"<option value='"+NewOption+"'>"+NewOption+"</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById('field2').value = document.getElementById('field1').value;
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="field1">
    <br>
    <select id="field2">
        <option value="apples">apples</option>
        <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
        <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
</body>
```